# Snowflake Stored Procedure multiple statements list parameters

Tags: javascript, sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to create a Snowflake stored procedure with multiple SQL statements, and input multiple parameters which happen to be a list. Having trouble. Is it possible?

My attempt:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_MULTI_STATEMENT(NAME string , AGE string)
returns string not null
language javascript
as
$$
var cmd = `
update TABLE_1 set SOMETHING1 = 'OK' where NAME in (${NAME});
update TABLE_2 set SOMETHING2 = 'GREAT' where AGE in (${AGE});
    `
    var sql = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: cmd});
    var result = sql.execute();
    return 'DONE';
    $$;
```

When I call my SP I would like it to be:

```
call SP_MULTI_STATEMENT('Andy, Brian, Christa','21,23,24');
```

Comment: What kind of "Having trouble" are you having? Any error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of it looks good, but you need to add more quoted escapes to the list of names.

This example works:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_MULTI_STATEMENT(NAMES string , AGES string)
returns string not null
language javascript
as
$$
var cmd = `
select *
from (select 'a' name, 33 age)
where NAME in (${NAMES})
and AGE in (${AGES});
    `
    var sql = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: cmd});
    var result = sql.execute();
    if(result.next()) {
        return result.NAME;
    }
    return 'no results'
    $$;
    
call SP_MULTI_STATEMENT('\'a\', \'b\', \'c\'', '30, 31, 32, 33');
```